# Huge number while calculating error of predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I built a multiple linear regression model. My prediction and test values looks close as follow:
[image]
I want to calculate error percentage. But got huge numbers in this piece of code:

```
from sklearn import metrics
print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
```

Output:

```
Mean Absolute Error: 137610.86451426445
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, while performing the regression, we **normalize the data** fed to the model. This improves predictions and avoids the gradients to actually explode.

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201909/when-to-normalize-data-in-regression) for more information.

You can carry out normalization in a simple way using,

```
x_new = x - x.min() / ( x.max() - x.min() )
```

Where `x` is the sample from the dataset, `x.min()` returns the minimum value from the dataset and `x.max()` returns the maximum value from the data. `x_new` is the normalized value between 0 and 1.

Hence, you get values which belong to the interval `[ 0 , 1 ]`.

> Also, we get smaller values for loss functions like MAE and MSE. The gradients don't explode or have huge values. The training goes on smoothly.

**Tip:**

Also, read about Standardization of data. [Standardization vs. Normalization](http://www.dataminingblog.com/standardization-vs-normalization/) could be a great read. Maybe, you can read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-preparation-and-preprocessing-is-just-as-important-creating-the-actual-model-in-data-sciences-2c0562b65f62).